# k-nearest neighbor training fails on CrossTable() with error for x and y having different lengths

Tags: r, knn, training-data

Does this possibly have something to do with the order in which I removed "NA" values?  I removed them before normalizing, is this correct?  I've searched through the other "related" posts on train/test lengths not matching but they do not seem to address my issue.

The complete code is included.  Very appreciate any tips.  Thank you!!!

[image]

```
library(caret)
library(class)
library(gmodels)

heart_data <- read.csv("https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/heart-disease/processed.cleveland.data") #import heart data
str(heart_data)

colnames(heart_data) <- c("age","sex","cp","trestbps","chol","fbs","restecg","thalach","exang","oldpeak","slope","ca","thal","num")

is.na(heart_data)
df <- data.frame(heart_data)
which(is.na(df))
sum(is.na(df))
colSums(is.na(df))
df_nonas <- na.omit(df)

df_nonas$num <- with(df_nonas, ifelse(num >=1, 1, 0)) 
df_nonas$num <- as.factor(df_nonas$num) 

min_max_norm <- function(x) {(x-min(x)) / (max(x) - min(x))}
df_norm <- as.data.frame(lapply(df_nonas[,c(1,4,5,8,10)], min_max_norm))
cat_vars <- as.data.frame(lapply(df_nonas[,c(3,7,11:13)],as.factor))

dummy <- dummyVars(~.,data=cat_vars,fullRank = TRUE)
df_dummy <- as.data.frame(predict(dummy,newdata=cat_vars)) 
df_all <- cbind(df_nonas$sex,df_nonas$fbs,df_norm,df_dummy,df_nonas$num) 
set.seed(789) 

idx <- sample(2, nrow(df_all), replace=TRUE, prob=c(0.7, 0.3))
df_train <- df_all[idx==1, ] 
df_test <- df_all[idx==2,]   
df_train_label <- df_all[idx==1,ncol(df_train)] 
df_test_label <- df_all[idx==2,ncol(df_test)]
knn_pred.1 <- knn(train=df_train,test=df_test,cl=df_train_label,k=1) 

CrossTable(x=df_test_label, y=df_train_label, prop.chisq=FALSE)
```

Comment: Revise code - > CrossTable(x=knn_pred.1, y=df_test_label, prop.chisq=FALSE)

Comment: It's different train and test length . You have to compare with what the model expected.

Comment: Indeed I had incorrect code for CrossTable. This is correct:  CrossTable(x=knn_pred.1, y=df_test_label, prop.chisq=FALSE)